# function to return string angularjs firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I started angularjs 2 days ago (...) 
I'm currently asking myself how to create a function that fetches my firebase data and depending on the child, it returns a string.

Seems pretty simple when I say it, but harder to do...

I could fetch the data one by one but the problem is that there are a total of 84 childs!!

**My Context**
The website retrieves from firebase if a person is working night, day or evening, for the 7 days of the week, for 4 weeks in a month (3x7x4 = 84).
An example of one of my child is: **Saturday1Night: true** where "1" means week 1.

**What I tried**

```
function getOneDay(currentUserId, key, query, text){
  firebase.database().ref().child('Users').child(currentUserId).child(key).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    /* query is "Saturday1Night" */
    if(datasnapshot.$value === null && datasnapshot.id === null) {
      /* not working */
      text = 'X';
    }else{
      /* value is "true", person is working */
      text = query;
    }

  })
  return text;
}
```

Now my real question is, how can I, like in java for example, create a function that returns a string? How can I display it in my $scope?

**html**

```
<h1>{{s1n}}</h1>
```

**angularjs**

```
$scope.s1n = text; //??
$scope.s1n = getOneDay(/*uid*/, /*key*/, "Saturday1Night", $scope.s1n) //??
```

Thank you in advance, have a good night/day!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database APIs are asynchronous, meaning that `once()` returns immediately.  Some time later, it will invoke your callback when the data becomes available.   This means that your `getOneDay` function also returns immediately with an undefined value, because `text` doesn't have a value at the time it's evaluated.

You can't really make a function that returns a value from Realtime Database.  You need to deal with its asynchronous APIs with the promises or callback they provide.

[Read here to learn more about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous.](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93)

Answer (score 0):

You can try async-await:

```
    async function getOneDay(currentUserId, key, query, text){

        var datasnapshot = await firebase.database().ref().child('Users').child(currentUserId).child(key).once('value');

        if(datasnapshot.$value === null && datasnapshot.id === null) {
          /* not working */
          text = 'X';
        }else{
          /* value is "true", person is working */
          text = query;
        }


      return text;
    }
    $scope.s1n = await getOneDay(/*uid*/, /*key*/, "Saturday1Night", $scope.s1n)
```